# Bind function not recognized in backbone app

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to learn backbone and integrate it into this app i'm building. The goal is to query an api that returns some JSON,

I then want to render it in a table. Right now, I'm getting the JSON back, but not sure how to get the collection to talk with the view.

I got most of this from a tutorial that may be old at this point. So any suggestions or tutorials on how to move forward would be great.

The error i'm getting is

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.jds_collection.refresh is not a function
```

Heres the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var Jd = Backbone.Model.extend({
  });

  JdsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/blogs'
    model: Jd,
    initialize: function(){
      console.log("Initialize JdsCollection collection");
      this.jdtable = new JdTable;
      this.bind("refresh", this.jdtable.renderTable);
    }
  });

  JdTable = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#mainTable"),
    initialize: function(){
      console.log("Initialize JdTable view");
      // console.log($("#mainTable2"));
      this.$el.html("This is the inital content");
    },
    renderTable: function(collection){
      console.log(collection);
    }
  });

  AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#appview"),
    initialize: function(){
      console.log("Initialize AppView view");
      this.jds_collection = new JdsCollection;
      // this.loadResults({});
    },
    events: {
      "keyup #jd-search-input": "loadResults"
    },
    loadResults: function(event){
      query = $(event.currentTarget).val();
      $.when(this.ajaxGetJds( query ) )
      .then($.proxy(function( response ){
        entries = response.Output.Results;
        console.log(this.jds_collection);
        this.jds_collection.refresh(entries);
      }, this ) );
    },
    ajaxGetJds: function( query ){
      return $.ajax(jds_api + "?searchText=" + query, {dataType: "jsonp", cache: true, data:{outputType: "JSONP"}});
    }
  });

  console.log($("#jd-search-input"));
  var appview = new AppView;
});
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but `bind` does not work the way you seem to think it does. You call it on a function and it *returns* a new function which calls the original function with a different value of `this`.

Comment: I think what you want is `this.jds_collection.reset(entries);` instead of `this.jds_collection.refresh(entries);`

Comment: Your code is a little inside-out. It is generally considered bad form for a collection or model to be referencing a view, normally the view would listen for events from the model or collection rather than the other way around. And aren't you missing some `var`s?

Comment: What are you trying to do..?